# Media Queries for iPhone 5 in desktop

Tags: html, iphone, css, media-queries

I tried to use this media query 
`@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) {}`
for the iPhone 5 responsive design. I can see the effects in my iPhone 5. But for that every time I need to upload the modified version to server. Is there any way to see the changes reflecting in this iPhone width by just re-sizing the window size? Or am I missing something stupid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can user ctrl+shift+m in mozila to test the effects.

Comment: What is the screen width to be given for Mobile devices? including iPhone 5?

Comment: you can add your own screen size here, standard width is 320 to 480 but you can test it for 320 to 767.